# How can I create a background color animation with fade?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, colors

How can I achieve a background color animation in WPF? [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFz7qFAHDII&t=136s) explains how to do it in Windows Forms only.

I've tried several things with no success.

Can it be done?

Comment: IIRC, Animations are the droid you are looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/animation-overview | No need for a manual timer like in that Windows Forms example. It is one of the areas where WPF is just unambigiously better then Windows Forms.

Comment: Totally, especially the ColorAnimation that's made for this purpose. If you come back with some code after you've tried something, it'll be easier to help.

Comment: I see this but If you can give me a Code example of what is being done in this video but ive tried a bunch of things with no success.

Comment: Please include those things in your question:)

Comment: @MsAthena123 for which purpose do you want this background? If you can answer on it i will provide source code example.

Comment: @MsAthena123: The example is clearly done in Windows Forms. A older, totally different Display Technology. You are not using Windows Forms, you are using WPF. All those modern things we had to do ourself or that were outright missing in Windows Forms? WPF has them. Usually in XAML.

Comment: This question, while perhaps downvote-worthy, is easily answerable (as demonstrated by the *accepted* answer) and not at all too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in XAML. Start animating the `Background.Color` property of the `Window` when it's loaded, using a `ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames`.

```xml
<Window.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="brush"/>
</Window.Background>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="brush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color">
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:05" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="Blue"/>
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="Red"/>
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="Yellow"/>
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03" Value="Green"/>
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:04" Value="Orange"/>
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:05" Value="Blue"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

From there and by reading more on animations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/animation-overview) and specifically on the `ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-color-by-using-key-frames), you'll be able to tweak it as per your needs and come back with a more specific issue.

Comment: This works amazingly just like I wanted but how do I make it loop? so its never ending?

Comment: It is already running in a loop because of the `RepeatBehavior="Forever"` markup.

Comment: nvm I fixed it but how can I slow the speed down? seems that was the issue causing it to stop